# Video overlay Video with ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

Video overlay Video with `ffplay`

I want the 2nd video to pop up 5 seconds later after 1st video start runs; 15 seconds later, I want the 2nd video to end (but the 1st video keeps playing)

The problem is, the 2nd video don't view the 1st 5 seconds.
It plays 5 to 15 + 5 seconds of the file but I want to play 0 to 15 seconds

I know the trick is to set PTS for the second video but where/how on this command?

My code:

```
ffplay.exe -autoexit -x 1280 -y 720 -f lavfi movie="video.AVI"[bg];movie="waterMark.AVI",scale=320:240[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=388:289:enable=between(t\,5\,15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffplay -autoexit -x 1280 -y 720 video.AVI -f lavfi "movie="waterMark.AVI",trim=0:15,setpts=PTS+5/TB,scale=320:240[fg];[in][fg]overlay=388:289:enable=between(t\,5\,20)"`

Comment: Thanx Gyan - perfect